# I get a "Build canceled" message when i try to start my Emulator in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

When I try to run my Android Emulator so i can test my app it doesn't start up, it debugs but then shows up on the bottom "Build canceled", as shown here (lower left corner): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr3Rw.jpg

I looked up one solution and it told me to enable HyperV and I did that

Other than that I didn't so much else other then look up a tutorial on how to setup the android device on my computer

How can I repair this problem? Thanks

Comment: `When I try to run my Android Emulator so i can test my app it doesn't start up`, are you just clicking the debug (play symbol) to debug when the emulator *is not running*? Or do you start the emulator first and then debug? I am asking because I had the same problem, I just start the emulator first, wait until fully ready and then debug; all works well for me doing this. Sometimes I can just debug and my emulator does launch, but I have better success launching the debugger first.